# Read Series Values from Excel Chart Data Series Using Apache POI HSSF

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi, poi-hssf

I want to extract the actual series data and values from a chart in xls file using Apache POI. Point Values like the pair (15.44956728, 7) as shown below. I managed to extract the title of the chart but could not do it with the needed data. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.extractor.ExcelExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("Hello, World");
        InputStream inp;
        try {
            inp = new FileInputStream("USRAK_00017_0.xls");
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(new POIFSFileSystem(inp));
            ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
            extractor.setFormulasNotResults(true);
            extractor.setIncludeSheetNames(true);
            String text = extractor.getText();
            //System.out.println(text);
            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFChart[] sheetCharts = HSSFChart.getSheetCharts(sheet);
            System.out.println(sheetCharts[0].getSeries()[0].getSeriesTitle());

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try `sheetCharts[0].getSeries()[0].getDataValues`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this return LinkedDataRecord

Comment: Yes and if the values are coming from sheet data, then [LinkedDataRecord.getFormulaOfLink](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/chart/LinkedDataRecord.html#getFormulaOfLink--) provides an array of [Area3DPtg](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/formula/ptg/Area3DPtg.html). This is where I would look further.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach I found is to dump the XLS file to XML content in fods format. Open Office can do this job via the following command:

```
soffice --headless --convert-to fods USRAK_00017_0.xls
```

Then you can parse the XML the way you like and parse the part you want to extract from the chart